# Using JavaScript, how do I write the same text to multiple HTML elements, or how do I write text to all HTML elements of the same class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing this program to take a root music note and populate tables with various scales from that root note. So, many of the tables cells will have the exact same value in them. I realize I can call my "useScale" function for every single  that I need to write text to but since there will be repeats, it seemed like there should be a way to run my function once and apply the results to multiple  but it did not work to use the document.getElementsByClassName("").innerHTML, I had been using "ById" which worked fine but each ID must be unique so, I can't write to multiple elements. Here's my code, I'd love some suggestions. 
many thanks

```
            Root Note <input type="text" name="defineRootNote" id="rootNoteCapture" size="2"/>
            <button onclick="findScale()">Submit</button>
        <table id="majorTriad">
            <th>Major Triad</th>
            <tr><td>1st</td><td class="root"> </td></tr>
            <tr><td>3rd</td><td class="3rd"> </td></tr>
            <tr><td>5th</td><td class="5th"> </td></tr>
        </table>
        <table id="minorTriad">
            <th>Minor Triad</th>
            <tr><td>1st</td><td class="root"> </td></tr>
            <tr><td>3 Flat</td><td class="3Flat"> </td></tr>
            <tr><td>5th</td><td class="5th"> </td></tr>
        </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function findScale(rootNote){
        var rootNote = document.getElementById("rootNoteCapture").value;
        rootNote = rootNote.toUpperCase();
        var scaleCheck = ["A", "A#", "AB", "B", "BB", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "DB", "E", "EB", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "GB"];
         if (scaleCheck.indexOf(rootNote) == -1) {
            document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = "Invalid Entry";

           }
           else {
                switch(rootNote){
                    case "AB":
                    rootNote = "G#";
                    break;
                    case "BB":
                    rootNote = "A#";
                    break;
                    case "DB":
                    rootNote = "C#";
                    break;
                    case "EB":
                    rootNote = "D#";
                    break;
                    case "GB":
                    rootNote = "F#";
                    break;
                    rootNote = rootNote;
                    }
                document.getElementsByClassName("root").innerHTML = rootNote;
                document.getElementsByClassName("3rd").innerHTML = useScale(rootNote, 4);
                document.getElementsByClassName("5th").innerHTML = useScale(rootNote, 7);
                document.getElementsByClassName("3Flat").innerHTML = useScale(rootNote, 3);
                }
         }
         function useScale(startPoint, offset){
            var scale = ["A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#"];
            var returnNote = null;
            var scalePoint = scale.indexOf(startPoint);
            for (var i = 0; i < offset; ){
                i = i + 1;
                //console.log(i);
                //console.log(scalePoint);
                scalePoint ++;
                if (scalePoint > 11) {scalePoint = 0;}
                }
                returnNote = scale[scalePoint];
                return returnNote;
         }
    </script>
```

Comment: Write a function `setElementsHTML(elmts, val)` that accepts an array (or array-like object) of elements and the value to set their `.innerHTML` to. Or have it accept the class name and call `getElementsByClassName()` within the function. The function will use a `for` loop. Then in other parts of your code you just call the function.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("") returns a array. You have to reference its elements like document.getElementsByClassName("")[i]

Comment: Show what you have actually tried.

Comment: You can also try jQuery if you like. Its simple like `$('.className').html('your text');` which will replace the given text in all elements having class `className`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through your elements gathered by `getElementsByClassName()`.

```
var myElements = document.getElementsByClassName("className"); //assign this class name to each of the elements you want to work with
for(i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++)
{
     myElements[i].innerHTML = "value to set";
}
```

Comment: I should have realized getElementsByClassName would return an array, Thanks

Comment: In case someone else is looking for this, I actually couldn't get this to work until I added ".length" in the for loop after the class name for(i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++)
{ myElements[i].innerHTML = "value to set";
}

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use vanilla, it pays to define a couple helpers that make the particular and other related tasks much simpler:

```
function $(css){return [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(css));}
function setProp(a){ a[this[0]]=this[1]; };


   $(".root") // gather all elms matching this selector
   .forEach(  // functional for-loop replacement
     setProp,     // run the setProp function to set properties on all matches
     ["innerHTML", "Hello World"] // define the property name and value to be set
   );

    // or  more succinctly:
 $(".root").forEach(setProp, ["innerHTML", "Hello World"]);

//you can do something else to a different set without re-coding a loop:
 $(".3rd").forEach(setProp, ["title", "Hola Amigo"]);
```

with a 2-line jQuery replacement, we get chaining and re-usability, the two things that make this task trivial in jQuery.